# Google Spreadsheets formula question: do not include cell in a formula if blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am a music teacher and I use the following formula to calculate my students performance grades:

```
=100-SUM(F3-5)*-7
```

How can I change the formula so it only calculates a grade if there is data in the cell?

Additionally I use this formula to calculate the average of my students daily participation/conduct and performance grade:

```
=100*SUM(G3:H3)/200
```

Same basic question as above, how can I change the formula so it only runs if there is data in H3 and if there is not the solution equals G3?

Comment: I don't understand your first formula. Please write down what you actually want to compute. The way I understand it, you add up the values in F3, F4 and F5, multiply them by 7, and then add 100 to it. (the two minuses cancel each other out).

Comment: Please clarify `SUM(F3-5)`? If you subtract, why use `SUM`. If it is a typo for `SUM(F3-F5)`, then the same remark can be made.

Comment: My question has been answered but to clarify for you my students get a performance grade out of 5. 5=100 4=93 3=86 etc. So if there grade is a 5 F3=5 100-(5-5)*-7= 100% if they get a 4 then 100-(4-5)*-7= 93%, and so on. I am still new to formulas in spreadsheets, I literally started trying to figure this stuff out last week, so I may not even need SUM in the formula. I just haven't learned the various rules yet. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Then I suggest to write it like this: `100-((5-5)*-7)`. The extra brackets will give (somebody else) more insight. To give even more clarity, use this: `100-ABS((5-5)*7)`. This will turn all outcome between the brackets into a positive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IF function, for reference check the following

[Google spreadsheets function list](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240291)

so for the **students performance grades**, you could use the following

```
=IF(F3<>"", 100-SUM(F3-5)*-7, "")
```

and for the **students daily participation/conduct and performance grade**

```
=IF(H3<>"", 100*SUM(G3:H3)/200, G3)
```

Comment: Thank You!!! These work awesome!!! Now I just have to do my homework and figure out why so I can start answering questions instead of asking them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula, using an `IF` condition:

```
=if(H3=""; G3; 100*SUM(G3:H3)/200)
```

This means that if H3 equals `""` (i.e. is empty), show the contents of G3 only, otherwise compute the result of the formula in the third argument instead.